# How can I verify that I make a proper POST via cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, json, bash, curl

I have a sample json object contain these data. I'm trying to store those data in a variable, and passing through **curl POST**

```
$json = '{
    "mac": "1234567890",
    "dns": "8.8.8.8,4.2.2.1",
    "acl_mode": 1
}';

$url = 'http://my-site.com/api';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('json' => $json)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

dd($result);
```

---

My result is 500

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "error_code": 1005
}
```

---

- Is the way I set up my curl post wrong ?

Comment: what does the endpoint expect in terms of `POST` payload, I see that you `json_encode` an array of a `json` string this doesn't look right

Comment: try this `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json' => $json));` to send the actual json string as a `POST` payload, don't double encode it

Comment: @AlexAndrei I really appreciate your concern on this. Trying your suggestion now.

Comment: Not sure if CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is affecting the issue, but CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS doesn't make any sense here. It should be:  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json' => $json));` Also, make sure the `Content-Type` header is okay.

Comment: @felipsmartins According to the 4th list on my wireshark capture result, the header is `OK`

Comment: @ihue I would advise you to use Chrome Dev Tools or Firefox dev tools and trace full request cycle. Then replicate in PHP.

Comment: @felipsmartins: Sure, thanks for your advise, I will learn how to use them after this issue.

Comment: @felipsmartins : I tried you suggestion. As soon as I hit submit, the page hang almost 3 mins now.

Comment: @AlexAndrei : Your suggestion and Felip is the same, and now the page seem to be hanging. I'll update my post.

Comment: yes, see the first question also, what are you supposed to send to that URL, do you have any docs or successful requests?, can you share the bash script that works?

Comment: let's continue this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94935/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-33672813-how-can-i-verify-that-i-make-a-proper

Comment: I know this has been resolved but you can always test your HTTP requests using httpbin.org. For this example you could post to https://httpbin.org/post

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll use it next time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing with `curl` in the terminal we found out that the endpoint consumes the entire `POST` payload without a key.

This was used for testing

```
curl -X POST -d '{"mac": "1234567890","dns": "8.8.8.8,4.2.2.1","acl_mode": 1}'  http://mysite/api
```

So sending the `$json` payload as it is, without the `json_encode` and the `array` encapsulation.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
```

worked just fine.